# Is there a way to emulate 2 CPU Cores?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

My app is ASP.NET MVC.

I am using a lot of parallel processing on my local machine (8 cores) and things are running very smoothly.

But when I roll to Azure Medium Instance (2 cores), during testing, I get weird slow downs and program stops working sometimes.

Is there a way to emulate 1, 2 or another number of cores to match what will happen in production environment?

Comment: Can you post come code, showing how you're using parallel processing.

Comment: Ensure that you are testing in the Windows Azure Emulator and not just plain ol' debugging.  Things run differently in the azure environment and that could be the cause of your error.  As stated below, unless you have some extremely intricate multi-threading going on, the worst that should happen is a slower processing / less throughput from the machine.

Comment: I tried using Azure Emulator, but it is using 8 cores of my local PC no matter what kind of target machine I specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could try setting the process affinity for the development server.  To do that, (assuming Windows 7) open task manager, right-click the server process and select `Set Affinity...` and select the cores you want it to run on.

Just managed to find a way around @Dai's answer above, but it means you'll have to start the development server yourself.  This `.bat` file runs notepad.exe using two cores (you can verify that by checking its affinity within task manager):

```
start /affinity 0x03 notepad.exe
```

The `0x03` specifies core 1 and core 2.  The help command was a bit confusing, but it seems it combines those to get the result (as in, 1 + 2 = 3, unless I've misunderstood it).  So if you need to change to a different set of cores, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnH's method seems the best, but you'd have to do it every time w3wp.exe runs on your machine. An alternative is to restrict your operation to 2 threads (or 4 if using hyperthreading). We need more information about how you're processing information in parallel.

A parralelisable problem should just run 4 times as fast on an 8-core machine as opposed to the 2-core Azure VM, but getting 'program stops working' situations means you've got a bug there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fully help the situation, but you can set the [`MaxDegreeOfParalellism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) for each core.  This way you can limit the threads that run.